# Is there any AAC encoder for Flash? Maybe Alchemy?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I would like to encode audio recorded by Flash with AAC codec on the client. (The audio is less than 10 seconds)

Does anyone know of any AS3 or Alchemy library that could do this?

What could be a workaround? Java applet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not, I used FAAC/FAAD2 with minor changes with Alchemy.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly porting from Java: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jaadec/files/0.8.4/ would be the easiest option because the language is similar. If you thought about using Java applet alongside Flash, then I would've expected the marshaling expenses to bee too high to make sending sound samples back and forth a viable idea.

It's also worth noting that while there are many free / opensource implementations of the format, it is a patented technology. I'm not sure of the legal terms of use, but might be a good idea to check that too.